# Solr - Get more next "cursorMark" indices to allow a real pagination

Tags: solr, pagination

i'm developing an application, and the database is managed by Solr v8.1.

I have the necessity of create a pagination system, and i have read that cursors are advised for this type of operations.

The problem is: if i want create a pagination system, that will show to the end-user more than 1 next page, how can i do this?

Normally solr will return only 1 nextCursor index, but what about next 2/3/4 or more pages? Is this possible? Is possible have the same behaviour for previous cursors?

Checking the documentation, seems a continue fetch using the next cursor is mandatory, but i don't think that this is a smart solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is regular pagination if those are important features. CursorMarks are (very) useful for certain use cases, but might not give you any additional performance in your case.

You can however use cursorMarks, but a cursorMark won't tell you how far into a result set you've come (or how many rows are left - just how many rows there are in total. You can still keep track of this manually in your UI). The cursorMark only tells Solr "this is the last entry I showed, so start returning values from here..". This is useful for *deep pagination* across a cluster with many nodes, as it greatly reduces the required number of results to fetch from each node in the cluster.

If you decide to use a cursorMark, keep track of the current offset, the page size and the page number in your URL. You won't be able to let people skip directly to page X, but you can at least show how many results that remain (this is the same strategy as applied by Gmail).